# how to add two matrices in haskell

Tags: haskell, matrix, linear-algebra, hmatrix

I am trying to use Haskell's Linear Algebra library to compute some eigenvalues, but first I need to try to add matrices first.

```
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra.Data
matrix 3 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ]  + matrix 3 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ] 

(3><3)
 [  2.0,  4.0,  6.0
 ,  8.0, 10.0, 12.0
 , 14.0, 16.0, 18.0 ]
```

However, if I try to represent another way I get error message

```
( 3 >< 3 ) [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ]  + ( 3 >< 3 ) [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ] 

No instance for (Element a0) arising from a use of ‘print’
The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
```

I am not even sure about `matrix 3 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ]` since I would like to specify that I want a 3 × 3 matrix.  Where did the other 3 go?

Comment: I don't know how to solve your main problem, but regarding your last point: the second 3 is inferred from the length of the list. Given a Rx3 matrix with 9 elements, R must equal 3. `(><)` will truncate lists to produce matrices of the desired dimension, so `(2 >< 2) [1..]` evaluates to `(2 >< 2) [1,1,1,1]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem arises from the difference in type signatures.

```
 matrix :: Int -> [ℝ] -> Matrix ℝ
 (><) :: Storable a => Int -> Int -> [a] -> Matrix a
```

So actually `matrix 3 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ]` has type `Matrix ℝ` while `( 3 >< 3 ) [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ]` has type `(Num a, Foreign.Storable.Storable a) => Matrix a`. Then, the problem is suddenly tractable. Until you specify what `a` is, you don't know what `(+)` is, so you can't actually evaluate the sum of the matrix (only produce thunks), hence you can't print it.

A quick fix is to specify the type of your matrix

```
(3 >< 3) ([1..9] :: [ℝ])  + (3 >< 3) ([1..9] :: [ℝ])
```

which outputs (given the right imports):

```
(3><3)
 [  2.0,  4.0,  6.0
 ,  8.0, 10.0, 12.0
 , 14.0, 16.0, 18.0 ]
```

#### Some bonus info

I wanted to do `(3 >< 3) ([1..9] :: [Integer]) + (3 >< 3) ([1..9] :: [Integer])`, but note that the `Num` instance of `Matrix` has `(Container Matrix a, Num (Vector a)) => Num (Matrix a)` so we need `Vector a` to also have a `Num` instance. However, you can check that `Vector Integer` does not have a num declaration. Alternatives that work:

```
Num (Vector Double)  
Num (Vector Float)   
Num (Vector (Complex Double))    
Num (Vector (Complex Float))
```

Comment: are there alternatives for typing ℝ ?

Comment: `( 3 >< 3 ) ( [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ]:: [Float])  + ( 3 >< 3 ) ([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ] :: [Float])` seems to work

Comment: Yeah, my edit. `Double`, `Float`, `Complex Double`, and `Complex Float` are the ones that should work out of the box.